# Node js await for an async call made in catch block throwing error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm completely new to javascript and was learning how to use `await` with async functions. In my case I'm trying to wait for an async function to complete which I've called from a catch block. It isn't working with the message `The await operator can only be used with async functions`.

```
begin().then( () =>
    console.log("done")
)

async function begin() {
    await shouldFail().then( message =>
        console.log(message)
    ).catch( () => {
        await shouldFail().then( message => // The await here is not working. 
            console.log(message)
        ).catch( message =>
            console.log(message)
        )
    })
}

async function shouldFail(){
    await sleep(1000)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('failed'))
}
```

I can understand this could be happening because the catch method might not be async. I've tried to simplify my case with the above code. What would be the best way to know when the async function called inside the catch block is completed? I want the begin to only return after the catch block has executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to definition: await can be used only in async functions.

So your nested function has to async be as well

```js
async function begin() {
    await shouldFail().then( message =>
        console.log(message)
    ).catch( async () => { // here -----------------
        await shouldFail().then( message => 
            console.log(message)
        ).catch( message =>
            console.log(message)
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
begin().then( () =>
    console.log("done")
)

async function begin() {
    await shouldFail().then( message =>
        console.log(message)
    ).catch(async () => {  //**Just add a async here**
        await shouldFail().then( message => // This should work now
            console.log(message)
        ).catch( message =>
            console.log(message)
        )
    })
}

async function shouldFail(){
    await sleep(1000)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('failed'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use async/await then you don't need to add the then and catch block.

You can read more about async/await on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

**Sample code with async/await**

```
begin().then(() =>
    console.log("done")
)
async function begin() {
    try {
        let message = await shouldFail();
        console.log(message)
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            let message = await shouldFail();
            console.log(message)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(message)
        }
    }
}
async function shouldFail() {
    await sleep(1000)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('failed'))
}
```